# How To Detect Removable Drives (USB, SD) In ElectronJS/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, powershell, electron

I'm using node-powershell to run a Powershell script every 5 seconds to retrieve the list of connected removable media drives for an ElectronJS desktop app with Angular front-end.  It works...

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='2'"
```

Is there a way to do this without a constantly running setInterval, or to simply trigger an event when a USB device/SD card is plugged in or removed?

Goal: The app is intended for internal Windows users at my company.  The UI shows tabs for each connected drive with drive letter and details, and adds or removes tabs accordingly.  I'm trying to see if there's a "better" way of doing this more efficiently than the setInterval and Powershell script method that I currently have.  While it works, it feels like there could be a better way that I'm not aware of.  [usb-detection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/usb-detection) doesn't really work for me since it's USB only and doesn't provide a drive letter.

Comment: Not a node.js expert but in powershell you can attach to WMI events and listen for a device to be connected/disconnected. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805166/start-powershell-script-when-usb-drive-is-inserted) which is for launching a script on insertion. You could simply adjust the action to whatever you need.

Comment: You can use `Register-WmiEvent` to detect theUSB flash drive is insertion and you can take actions based on it.